# how can we print nulls last in mysql

Tags: mysql, null, oracle12c

I have an below mentioned oracle query where bulk record is varchar (600), activation_member_key is bigint and priority is INT. In this query, I need to print bulk record order by activation_member_key and priority desc and nulls last. Please help me, how can nulls be printed in last in MySQL 5.7. here is query in oracle:

```
select replace(replace(bulk_record, CHR(13), ''), CHR(10), '') as BULK_RECORD 
from eamp.temp_hlth_stmt_bulk 
order by activation_member_key, priority desc nulls last
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are only selecting BULK_RECORD so ordering by activation_member_key and priority wouldn't matter? I think you could just have

```
SELECT replace(replace(bulk_record, CHR(13), ''), CHR(10), '') as BULK_RECORD 
FROM eamp.temp_hlth_stmt_bulk 
ORDER BY BULK_RECORD ASC NULLS LAST
```

unless I'm missing something. What is your current query returning?

Comment: my query in oracle is returning highest value of priority in the first row and so on and nulls in last. My problem here is, "NULLS LAST" can be used in oracle but not in MySQL, so what can I use in MySQL to print nulls in last in this scenario